# What are the core.xxxxx files created by tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, jupyter

I've been using Tensorflow 2.0 in Jupyter Lab and I notice that there are files created called `core.xxxxx` such as :

```
core.18564
core.21528
core.28128
```

and more in the same naming convention format.

I've tried to open them in an editor (VI) and when I do my editor crashes (for now at least). These files are between 7 GB to 37 GB each (!!!)

**Question**: What are these files and what is their purpose?

Note: I've looked on Stackoverflow and to the best of my knowledge, I can't seem to find the answer here. I apologize if this turns out to be a duplicate.

Comment: These are linux core dump files because the program is crashing for some unknown reason. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump

Comment: @WilliamD.Irons Thanks a ton. Could you please post this as an answer so I can upvote + accept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are linux core dump files because the program is crashing for some unknown reason.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump for more info.

The number in the file name is process id that created the core file.

They can be removed to recover disk space.